# how to customize jquery-jtable create dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, crud, jquery-jtable

I am creating simple demo CRUD application using jtable [jable.org](http://jtable.org/)

Jtable contains only two data columns

StartTime and EndTime

I can specify type field as **date** if I want to show **Date-Picker** in create modal window, but I don't have any idea how to show **datetimepicker** in the create modal dialog box.

Can I customize the create modal dialog box in jtable js.

```
$('#MaintenanceTime').jtable({
    jqueryuiTheme: true,
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    title: 'The Roles are as follows:-',
    messages: {
        loadingMessage: 'Fetching Data from Server',
        addNewRecord: 'Add New MaintenanceTime',
    },
    actions: {

        listAction: '@Url.Action("ListMaintenanceTime")',
        updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateMaintenanceTime")',
        deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteMaintenanceTime")',
        createAction: '@Url.Action("AddMaintenanceTime")'

    },
    fields: {
        ATMaintenanceID: {
            key: true,
            title: 'Id',
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false
        },
        StartDate: {
            title: 'Start Time'
            //type: 'datetime',
            //displayFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        },
        EndDate: {
            title: 'End Time'
            //type: 'date',
            //displayFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        },

    }
});
```

Thanks for reviewing my question.

Comment: Can you clarify: as far as I understand, you would like to use Datetime instead of only date in a field when you create something in your table, right?

Comment: @NicolasR exactly...! that's what I was asking in this question. It will be great help to me if you provide better solution for this problem.

Comment: I used to implement it at the beginning of this year, I got to find my sources!

Comment: Sorry, looking back to my sources it was not jtable that I customize but a validation engine. But you may be interested in the commit of gbisheimer here: https://github.com/gbisheimer/jtable/commit/e40d9c4bd9c65adb56b43a9c233f65c9bc7a5cb9

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks, Nicolas that sounds great.

Comment: FYI, I also used Trent Richardson's timepicker which is a good tool. Beware of the not-up-to-date versions in the commit. I may formulate an answer to the question with these comments for better visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a **datetime** picker (not only date) in the jQuery's jTable plugin for an input in your CRUD actions, there is not dedicated `type` in the parameters ([jtable doc](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-type)):

> password / date / textarea / radiobutton / checkbox / hidden

Because the `date` format allows only jQuery Datepicker date formats.

---

A GitHub user has made the following commit to implement the dateTime type: https://github.com/gbisheimer/jtable/commit/e40d9c4bd9c65adb56b43a9c233f65c9bc7a5cb9

You can start from his work to implement your part. It uses the timePicker from Trent Richardson (can be found on GitHub also, [here](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)), but as far as I looked, the implementation of G. Bisheimer may not be up to date (timePicker not up to date, latest jTable compatibility?)